# Error with deleting items from Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In my Google Form I have 5 sections, 5 items : one item on each section, 4 List items and 1 CheckboxGrid item. After using this code for clearing form from items:

```
function clearAll(form){
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    form.deleteItem(i);
  }
}
```

I have an error **"Cannot open item with index 5. Number of items available :5"**
It deleted all items but didn't touch sections.
Also tried different ways to delete items, such as:

```
function clearForm(){
 var items = form.getItems();
 while(items.length > 0){
  form.deleteItem(items.pop());
  }
 }
```

Which causes error **"Invalid form update request."** in line with *pop()* function. It deleted only last item.
Maybe there are some problems with access to items, sections?

Comment: Why would it delete the *sections* if your script is for deleting *items* ?

Comment: How can i avoid or delete sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a delete counter then I think you can do it like this:

```
function clearAll(form){
  var items=form.getItems();
  var d=0;//deleted items counter
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    form.deleteItem(i-d++);
  }
}
```

This also works for rows on a spreadsheet. And this allows you to increment normally through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because indexes are 0 (zero) based, in other words, on collection of 5 elements the last element's index is 4.

By the other hand, if you will use a loop to delete all the form items, including sections, it should iterate backwards.

```
function clearAll(form){
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i=items.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    form.deleteItem(i);
  }
}
```

Related

[Google Script - Forms - Issues Deleting Page Breaks/Sections - "Invalid data updating form"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42538674/1595451)

Comment: This code also occurs error "Invalid form update request." as version with pop(). Maybe this some problems with access to items/sections?

Comment: pop() returns the last element of an Array while deleteItem requires an integer